# Magento - Admin attribute name for concrete product

Tags: php, magento, attributes, label, admin

I have spend hours trying to figure out but failed. I need to extract a label and value for 'manufacturer' attribute in Magento. BUT I need to get the description which is in admin field - not the one which is store specific.

I have found many methods how to get store-specific, also I could extract all of the options for the attribute, but couldn't get just a combination of current article from product page + admin value + admin label (no matter from which store I am accessing it).

Would anyone be able to help on that?

This gives an array of all values+labels, but not for a concrete article:

```
<pre><code>
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer');
foreach ( $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true) as $option){
$attributeArray[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
}
</code></pre>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get the value of the product manufacturer and get the label from your array of options like this:

```
$manufacturerOfProduct = $product->getManufacturer();
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer');
foreach ( $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true) as $option){
   $attributeArray[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
}
var_dump("Product manufacturer value is ".$manufacturerOfProduct." and label is ".$attributeArray[$manufacturerOfProduct]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for help! Working great now!